# Can I inspect user go to some address he go to some website via the iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe

For example, I have a iFrame, which the src is [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), when people go to apple.com via the iframe, I would like to prompt a message to the user. How can I achieve it?

Can I have some kind of listener to listen to the iFrame current address using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The same origin policy will prevent you from doing that.

reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: How about the iframe itself change it scr?

Comment: I means, if the content inside iframe that I can control, let say, it will always go to www.mydomain.com, I can inject whatever I want.

Comment: Then it is possible. Send a normal request from mydomain to your site. Process the request in the backend logic. If the mydomain is also your site's domain, then you can directly access the object.

Comment: But the page which using the iframe is not belong to me.

Comment: I got confused. In your example, the google.com belongs to you or the apple.com belongs to you?  Then nothing is related to the iframe i think.